# Finding Project information on BIM360 vs ACC

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-construction-cloud

We have projects on both BIM360 and ACC, I get the list of projects from Data Management and then I want to differentiate active projects vs non-active and production vs template/sample/component.
The endpoint on ACC for project ([here](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/admin-projectsprojectId-GET/)) gives both classification and status where BIM360 ([here](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-:project_id-GET/)) only status, how can I tell if  a project is a template project on BIM360 ?
Thanks Jonathan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ACC GET Projects endpoint https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/admin-accounts-accountidprojects-GET/ should also works with BIM360 projects. You can filter with classification and platform as the picture attached. Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: So, from your answer I realised ( and checked) that  sending a bim360 projectid to the ACC endpoint of ../construction/admin/v1/projects/:projectId will give me data in the same manner as an ACC project. Thanks

Comment: Yes, but remember only GET endpoints work for BIM360 projects, those POST|PATCH|DELETE not work for BIM360 projects.